# Missing data in R using mice

Tags: r, r-mice

I am trying to impute missing data for nominal attributes(example: age, gender, education etc.) . How to do this in mice package of R?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help figure out your problem, it would be best if you can provide a reprex: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is the wrong venue for this type of question. I would suggest googling on how to create dummy variables prior to running `mice` functions.